# Google Calendar API filtering events in next 7 days

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, calendar

I was wondering how can I filter array to display all events in the next 15 days. When I try to get only start with toISOString I get results but I am not sure how to convert to the same format the date which I am trying to get(add days from today).

[https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list]

```
let now = new Date();
let today = (new Date()).toISOString();
let nextWeek = new Date();
nextWeek.setDate(now.getDate() + 15);
let events = response.result.items;
const sortedEvents = events.filter(event =>
   event.start.dateTime >= nextWeek 
   && event.end.dateTime <= nextWeek
);
setEvents(sortedEvents);
```

Expected: Events within 15 days
Actual: Empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to find the answer, the trick was to format date in my filter method.

```
const sortedEvents = events.filter(event =>
event.start.dateTime >= today
&& event.end.dateTime <= nextWeek.toISOString()
);
```